# C/C++ - Storing characters from file into a 2d char array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, char

I'm trying to store characters who are letters from a file in a 2-D array, and after I finish with the last word on the first line , I want to go to the next line and do the same. (I presumed i have 4 lines in my text).

Here is my code :

```
void getPoem(char *filePath){
    ifstream f(filePath);

    int NumberOfRows=0;
    int NumberOfColumns=-1;
    int NumberOfColumns_Clone=-1;
    char matrix[100][100]={0};
    char s[100];
    do{
        f.getline(s, 100, '\n');
        for(int i=strlen(s)-1;i>=0;i--)
            if(isalpha(s[i]))
            matrix[NumberOfRows][++NumberOfColumns]=s[i];
        matrix[NumberOfRows][++NumberOfColumns]=NULL;
        NumberOfColumns--;
        NumberOfColumns_Clone=NumberOfColumns;   // I used this so i don't lose the nr_of_columns
        NumberOfColumns=0;
        NumberOfRows++;
        matrix[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns]='\0';
    }
    while(NumberOfRows<4);

        for (int i = 0; i<=NumberOfRows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<=NumberOfColumns_Clone; j++)
                cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

My output is terrible , when i print it it goes forever and my program beeps . I know it's bad i just want to know where I've done it wrong.

I don't want to use "string" that's why i'm struggling with "char".

Any help would be appreciated . 
Thank you so much !

Comment: why don't you use the debugger? you will find the bug and you'll also learn something...

Comment: I did use it , and it shows me that the matrix has the words I need but also blank characters after them , and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NumberOfColumns` and `NumberOfColumns_Clone` are simple variable in a loop : at the end of the loop you have the value of the last iteration and all previous values are lost.

You could :

- either change `NumberOfColumns_Clone` to an array and keep the size of each row

  ```
  int NumberOfColumns_Clone[100];
  ...
      NumberOfColumns_Clone[NumberOfRows]=NumberOfColumns;   // I used this so i don't lose the nr_of_columns
  ...
      for (int i = 0; i<=NumberOfRows; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j<=NumberOfColumns_Clone[i]; j++)
              cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
          cout << endl;
      }
  ```
- or use the null as a delimiter

  ```
      for (int i = 0; i<=NumberOfRows; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j<=NumberOfColumns_Clone[i]; j++) {
              if (matrix[i][j] = 0) break;  // exit from inner loop on terminating null
              cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
          }
          cout << endl;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote this function... I hope this will help you!

```
void getPoem(char *filePath)
{
    ifstream f(filePath);
    int numberOfRows=0;
    int numberOfColumns=0;
    char matrix[100][100];
    char s[100];
    int i;
    do
    {
        f.getline(s,100);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
            if(isalpha(s[i]))
            {
                matrix[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns++]=s[i];

            }
    numberOfRows++;
    numberOfColumns=0;
    }while(numberOfRows<4);
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j];
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

To help you a little bit, I'll write what mistakes you did:

warning: missing braces around initializer for ‘char [100]’ [-Wmissing-braces]

warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘char’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]

Are simple warnings, but be sure that they will influence you're results.